# Give an example argument that produces incorrect results

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Python Script:**

```
def any_lowercase2(s):
     for c in s:
          if 'c'.islower():
               return 'True'
          else:
               return 'False'


print(any_lowercase2('Ansar'))
print(any_lowercase2('ansar'))
```

I was expecting to have an error but instead, I am getting output as `True` for both.

Comment: 'c' remove the quotes => c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will always return `True` because it's checking to see if the string `'c'` is lowercase, not the variable named `c`.

Change the condition to:

```
if c.islower():
```

The function will also return after only checking the first letter in the input string. You can fix this by moving the `else` case so it only returns after the loop is complete.

```
def any_lowercase2(s):
     for c in s:
          if 'c'.islower():
               return 'True'
     return 'False'
```

This will return `'False'` if the input is all uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

In this case if I where you, I would rather write an one-liner like:

```
def any_lowercase2(s):
     return s[0].islower()
```

Or if you want a loop:

```
def any_lowercase2(s):
     for c in s:
          return c.islower()
```

This will directly print the booleans since `islower` function gives `True` if it's lower case, and false if it's uppercase or non alphabetic.